# Drupal 7 Node Import from CSV

Tags: drupal, import, content-management-system

I'm trying to import some content from a CSV into [Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/drupal-7.0). I've tried the [Feeds module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) but it doesn't allow me to match fields to my content type—as far as I can tell—which is a problem.

Previously—in Drupal 6—I have used [Node Import](http://drupal.org/project/node_import) but this isn't supported in [Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/drupal-7.0). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 21):

The feeds module will work, you just need to do a title work.

1. Create a new importer at admin/structure/feeds/create
2. Change your Parser settings to use CSV
3. Check the CSV Parser settings once saved and make sure the correct delimiter is selected
4. Select "Node Processor" as your processor in your Processor type
5. Verify your Processor settings. Select your content type. **It is important to set a user for for the node author. There is currently a bug that will cause an error if the author is set to anonymous.**
6. Using the column names in your CSV map your columns to your Drupal 7 fields.
7. Finally, go to /import and run your feed import.

   That should do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

[Migrate](https://drupal.org/project/migrate) is very robust and can do all kinds of importation.

For very simple things feed is certainly enough.