# drupal feeds module csv import error

Tags: drupal, drupal-feeds

I am trying to import a CSV from a url using the feeds module, I set everything up but when I start the import I get the following error:

An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging information follows. Path: XXXXX StatusText: OK ResponseText: Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in XXXXX/sites/all/modules/feeds/includes/FeedsConfigurable.inc on line 149

I have traced that error to this code, specifically the last line:

```
  public function getConfig() {
    $defaults = $this->configDefaults();
    return $this->config + $defaults;
  }
```

Any idea why I am getting this error?

I removed the default mappings because they were for an RSS feed, with GUID title etc....Could this have something to do with it? Are those required?

Also there is a bug that provokes an error if input user is set to Anonymous, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730652/drupal-7-node-import-from-csv), that is not my problem.

also, this is configdefaults():

```
   * Return default configuration.
   *
   * @todo rename to getConfigDefaults().
   *
   * @return
   *   Array where keys are the variable names of the configuration elements and
   *   values are their default values.
   */
  public function configDefaults() {
    return array();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks even though it was a different error that patch worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if drupal.org/node/1213472 helps you